# Ruby CSV File creation outputting only one long row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, dropbox-api

I am having an issue while creating a CSV file in Ruby. This is my code:

```
filename = "filename-#{Time.now}.csv"
#temp_csv = Tempfile.new(filename)
csv_header = ["example", "example", "example", "example", "example"]
new_csv = CSV.open(filename, 'w') do |csv_object|
  csv_object << csv_header
  normalized_data.each do |data|
    csv_object << data
  end
end
```

Now, my problem is `filename` when saved to disk looks perfectly fine, with multiple rows. When I inspect `data` using binding.pry, it looks exactly as it should, an array with elements inside it. However, if I save `new_csv` an open it all the contents are jammed into one very long row, that start with `[[` meaning everything seems to be wrapped in an array... 
Why is this? I am stumped and I've spent several hours trying to solve the problem.

Ps.
`#tmp_csv` is commented out because that strategy did not work either, but ultimately what I wanted to create was a temp file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**More information Edit:**

As I said, `filename` is actually created well in my system, however I am then trying to upload this file to Dropbox using put_file method from the Dropbox API and when I open it in Dropbox everything there is in one line.

The way I am uploading is:

`client.put_file("#{DROPBOX_PATH}/example_file_#{Time.now}.csv", file_name)`
It is when I open it in dropbox that everything turns up to be in one line.

THis is how my `normalized_data` looks like and I believe this is fine:

```
[["text",
  "text",
  "text",
  "2016-02-09",
  3,
  "text",
  {},
  false,
  "text",
  {"text"=>{}, "text"=>1},
  ["text", "text", "text"],
  "text",
  {"text"=>"text", "text2"=>{}}],
...
...
```

Comment: How are you opening the file after it's written? Are you on Windows? What is `normalized_data`?

Comment: Can you include a (pseudo) `(normalized_)data` definition in your code? Like `normalized_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]` ...

Comment: Added a normalized_data example @Felix
@Jordan After the file is generated I am trying to upload it to dropbox. The `filename` in my system is fine. It's the one in Dropbox that gets malformed.

Comment: Well, I just figured it out. Sorry to waste your time, it turns out when you upload to Dropbox you have to open the CSV file first.. so I had to change my dropbox command to: `client.put_file("#{DROPBOX_PATH}/example_file_#{Time.now}.csv", File.open(file_name)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to save `new_csv` as is, since it is a result of `CSV.open(filename, 'w')`. Yes, it is an array of arrays, it is how CSV is represented inside ruby (an array of rows, each one being an array of columns.)

It is unclear, why would you try to save `new_csv` directly. Basicaly, this operation converts the mentioned above array of arrays to string and stores this string in the file.

The CSV itself is written properly (to `filename`,) as you’ve pointed out. Whether you want to keep working with CSV in the code, array of arrays is your choice.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I am going to accept this one because it guided me in the proper direction, letting me know my code was fine and that the actual error was further up the chain when uploading to dropbox. I was saving the new_csv out of frustration to see if that would make the text display properly but it was only aggravating the situation.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `normalized_data` is either a triple array like `[[['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']]]` or a flat array like `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

What it should be is an array of arrays like `[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']]`.
or a flat array

Your normalized_data should look like [['a', 'b', 'c']

Using this code:

```
require 'csv'

normalized_data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
new_data = CSV.open('file.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  normalized_data.each do |data|
    csv << data
  end
end

puts "New data:"
puts new_data.inspect
puts "File contents:"
puts File.read('file.csv')
```

The output is as expected:

```
New data:
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
File contents:
a,b,c
d,e,f
```